is it possible to select LWC datatable rows(multiple rows) with CTRL and SHIFT keys?
I want to build a UI that shows a list of records and it should allow me to do the following,

I should be able to select multiple rows with the CTRL key to select different records.
I should be able to select multiple rows with SHIFT Keys to select records in a sequence.
I should be able to drag the selected data table records to another target area of the component.

Is it feasible with a standard LWC datatable component? or does it need custom development for all the above requirements?

The standard lightning datatable has a checkbox column that works multi-select with the SHIFT key. Anything beyond this needs custom development. To state the likely reason why someone (not me) downvoted your question: You could have come to this conclusion yourself, looking at the documentation. If you want a better answer, describe your use case, state exactly how you want the user to select the table records and by what means to drag it - and also add what you already found out.

This is possible with custom data table but it is not possible with the standard LWC <lightning-datatable> component.
We need to use the custom SLDS data table to identify SHIFT and CTRL key presses on table rows.
when table row <tr> is clicked check in the handle function if the CTRL or SHIFT key is pressed with event.shiftKey or event.ctrlKey
<table>
 <tr onclick={handleRowClick} data-id="john_123" draggable="true">
   <td> John </td>
 </tr>
</table>

when we click on the table row <tr> we may be clicking any <div> in <td> or we may be clicking on any <td> but data-id attribute is mentioned in <tr> so we need to get the closest <tr> to get the data-id from that. Check the below function.
handleRowClick(event) {

   if(event.ctrlKey) {

      // Get the parent <tr> of the clicked <td>
      const row = event.target.closest('tr');

      // Get the 'data-id' attribute of the <tr>
      const rowId = row.getAttribute('data-id');
      
      //collect this rowId in the array to know which rows were clicked/selected
      this.selectedRows.push(rowId);

      //add the style class to row to highlight the row with a grey background to show it is selected
      row.classList.add('highlight-table_row');
   }
}

CSS to highlight table <tr>
.highlight-table_row {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

Similarly, we can write the SHIFT key logic.
To drag the selected table rows, we can set draggable="true" in <tr> and we can write the drag logic.
Please check this for Drag & Drop Native HTML API. This can be implemented in LWC as well.
